# Best way to represent structure where subclass is like a superclass with one object

Tags: python, inheritance, hash, subclass, self-reference

I want to represent a structure that is something like an unordered deck of cards (in Python 3.7, say), which has the property that a single card can be thought of as a deck of size one.

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self, cards, owner):
        self.owner = owner
        self.cards = cards


class Card(Deck):
    def __init__(self, number, suit, owner):
        self.number = number
        self.suit = suit
        super().__init__({self}, owner)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.number == other.number and self.suit == other.suit and self.owner == other.owner

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.number, self.suit, self.owner))


card = Card(5, 'clubs', 'me')
```

(The above returns `AttributeError: 'Card' object has no attribute 'owner'`)

If I wanted my deck to be ordered, this would be simple, since the `Card.__init__()` would just pass in the list `[self]` to the `Deck.__init__()`. However, I can't just pass in `{self}` to `Deck.__init__()`, since `Card.__hash__()` may require Deck attributes to already be set! There are plenty of workarounds; I could simply set `self.owner = owner` in `Card.__init__()`, or I could pass `[self]` to `Deck.__init__()` and then set `self.cards = set(cards)` in the body, but it seems weird to me that other parts of the code should depend on how the deck chooses to store its cards. Therefore, my question isn't how to *code* this, but rather the best way to *design* this kind of relationship so that I don't have to worry about these issues. Any ideas?

I searched for this question and didn't find anything, but it's pretty simple so I apologize if it's a duplicate. Thanks for reading!

Edit: If a deck of cards is a bad analogy for my structure, a (hopefully) more accurate analogy would be a polynomial, which is a sum of monomials, but each monomial is also a polynomial with just itself as a term.

Comment: This just doesn't make sense to me. Why shoehorn in inheritance when it is clearly composition? The better way to design this is *not to use inheritance*. I mean, a deck being composed of a collection of cards is like a prototypical example of OOP used in many tutorials.

Comment: I chose a deck of cards to make my example as simple as possible, but maybe that was a mistake. The key question here is about some structure with the above property, not about the best way to represent a deck of cards!

Comment: Your structure inherently makes no sense. Your confusing a container of things with the individual things. Even if this were the case, it makes no sense to make a Card class to being with. *Why use inheritance here*? What does it accomplish? It fundamentally does not fit with the model of inheritance. Even in your polynomial example, why use inheritance? Your Polynomial class would simply keep track of it's degree, so a monomial wouldn't be a subclass, it would simply have degree 1. An example in builtins are `str` objects, which contain other `str` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that your idea "a single card can be thought of as a deck of size one." is not quite coherent, and you've stumbled on a nicely concrete illustration of why.

A deck of one card is a fundamentally different concept from a single card, and in order for the deck-of-card to exist, a non-deck card must also independently exist.

You can see this by thinking about the operation "adding one card" — you should be able to do that to the deck, and it should result in a deck of two cards. But you should not be able to do that to a card, because then some other deck which already contains the card would suddenly be of mixed type — it would have some cards that are one card, and some that are two, which is not a way that decks of cards work (and would break iteration, etc).

So I think the correct choice here is to simply support breaking decks into smaller decks when you need to — it's fine to model moving a card out of the deck as "splitting the deck into two decks, one of N-1 cards and one of 1 card", but the 1-card deck still needs to have a non-deck Card object inside it, or you'll have problems.

Comment: Thanks, your answer made me realize why this was a bad idea. While I was planning on keeping my objects immutable, which kind of negates the "adding one card" dilemma, the structure I proposed would still cause issues when adding 0 cards to a 1-card deck, or removing n-1 cards from an n card deck. It would be clunky to always check if there is only 1 card when deciding what type to make the output.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to ignore the questionably of this design and focus on the error in the supplied code.

The `AttributeError` is caused by `{self}` in:

```
super().__init__({self}, owner)
```

This attempts to take the hash of `self` before it has been fully initialized.

Replace `{self}` with `[self]` and your code runs without issue.